# What command code function equal "this" in the case?

Tags: jquery, object

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log($("#question1 button").text());
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="question1">question 1
  <button class="option1">question1-1</button>
  <button class="option2">question1-2</button>
  <button class="option3">question1-3</button>
  <button class="option4">question1-4</button>
</div>
```

as title

What command code function equal "this" in the case ?

i try .text() and .children() seems output button group 1-1 ~ 1-4 .

i want to "this" function onclick can show what i click each individual option.

what other command code i can use ? like "this" in the case.

thanks

Comment: Try - `console.log($(this).text());`

Comment: not "this" command because after add other function have problem.

Comment: Try with `console.log($(event.target).text());`